# Project Euler 23: Why is my code so slow and what can I do to speed it up?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

Here is a link to the problem: [link](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23). My code seems to be slowing down exponentially but I can't identify why or a more efficient algorithm. My approach was to identify all of the abundant numbers up to the limit and identify the numbers up to the upper limit that are not sums of the numbers by subtracting each number from the original and seeing if the difference is inside the abundant numbers list. Any ideas as to what is going on and or a better approach to this problem?

Here is the code that I used:

```
import numpy as np 
import math
import itertools

def divisors(n): return sorted(np.unique(np.array([[x,n/x] for x in range(1,int(round(math.sqrt(n))+1)) if n%x == 0]).flatten()).tolist())[0:-1]



ubound = 28123
abundant_numbers = [x for x in range(1,ubound) if x < sum(divisors(x))] 


def is_sum_of_abundant(n):
    isob = False
    for i in abundant_numbers:
        if (n - i) <=0: 
            continue
        else:
            if (n - i) in abundant_numbers:
                isob = True 
    return isob

s = 0

for x in range(1,ubound):
    print "%.2f percent\n" % ((float(x)/ubound)*100)
    if is_sum_of_abundant(x):
        print "{} is abundant".format(x)
    else:
        s+=x
        print "{} is not abundant".format(x)
print s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you try is a better way to calculate the sum of the divisors - see the definition of the sigma function [here](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/SigmaFunction.html). Essentially you find the prime factors and use the fact that

```
sigma(ab) = sigma(a) * sigma(b)
sigma(p^n) = (p^(n+1)-1)/(p-1)
```

where sigma(n) is the sum of the positive divisors.